# Should your heuristic for an A* search algorithm be the same scale as your actual weights?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, a-star-search

I'm a bit confused about the scale of heuristics for implementing A* search. $f(n)$ is the total cost of travelling to a node $n$. It is calculated by $f(n) = g(n) + h(n)$. $g(n)$ is the cost of the path to node $n$ from the source node. $h(n)$ is a heuristic function that estimates the cost of the cheapest path from n to the goal. (Roughly summarised from [the wikipedia article on A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#:%7E:text=%20%20%20Class%20%20%20Search%20algorithm,%28%20b%20d%20%29%20%7Bdisplaystyle%20O%20...%20))

My question is should $h$ and $g$ be on the same scale? e.g. if g(n) to node n is 10 is it ok if the h(n) is 800?

I've read some conflicting takes on it where one example of using A* for plane routes had $g$ values in the range of 10-50 but $h$ values in the range 100 - 900 but elsewhere I read that they should be the same scale to avoid changing an A* search into a greedy best first search?

Comment: What does "scale" mean exactly? For example if `g` is in kilometers and `h` is in meters, that's obviously wrong. Or are we just eyeballing the magnitudes of the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can't possibly be on the same scale throughout the search, if by that you mean that $g(n) \approx h(n)$ for every node encountered near the search.  Near the start, you'll have $g(n) \approx 0$, so $g(n) \ll h(n)$.  Near the goal node, you'll likely have $h(n) \approx 0$, so $h(n) \ll g(n)$.

On the other hand, it *is* possible to have the range of values for $g$ (min across all nodes, to max across all nodes) to be similar to the range of values for $h$ (min across all nodes, to max across all nodes).  That is a good property.  In particular, the range of $g(n)$ will be from 0 to the distance to the goal; if $h(n)$ is perfect (exactly accurate), it will have the same range.

If $h(n) \ll g(n)$ throughout the search (i.e., for all nodes $n$), then the search becomes similar to Dijkstra's algorithm (in particular, if $h(n)=0$ everywhere, then it is devolves to exactly Dijkstra's algorithm).

If $g(n) \ll h(n)$ throughout the search (i.e., for all nodes $n$), then the search becomes similar to a greedy best first search using only $h(n)$ (in particular, if $g(n)=0$ everywhere, it devolves to exactly greedy best first).

Comment: I'm a bit unclearly on the first line of your answer. Perhaps I'm using the incorrect term but if your weights and heuristics are in the range of, say 1-10 for all nodes whether at near the source (where g may be 1 and h 10) or near the target (where now g may be 1 and h may be 10) arent they the same scale?

The second sentence makes it clearer, so if I was graphing a flight network where the weights were the price of a flight the euclidean distance between airports would be a bat heuristic.

Comment: @JulyJones, Good point.  Please see the updated answer.  There are multiple possible meanings for what "same scale" might be; I now try to address all of them in my revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have misunderstood the heuristic function.  It is supposed to give an *underestimate* on the distance from a node $n$ to the goal node $t$.  The closer this estimate is to the true value, the better A* will perform.

The only criterion for the heuristic function is that it never gives a higher value for $h(n)$ than the true cost of going from $n$ to $t$.

Let $\text{dist}(a, b)$ be the "true" distance from $a$ to $b$, and let $\text{dist}_0(a,b)$ be an underestimate (e.g. the Euclidean distance from $a$ to $b$ if you have a map).

If you are searching for a path from $s$ to $t$,
then $g(n)$ is defined to be $\text{dist}(s, n)$, whereas $h(n)$ is $\text{dist}_0(n, t)$.  So
$$ \text{dist}(s, n) + \text{dist}_0(n, t) = g(n) + h(n) = f(n).$$

There is nothing about *scale* of $g(n)$ and $h(n)$, except that $h(n)$ must give a lower value than (or equal to) the true distance from $n$ to $t$.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, when you talk about the "true value" are you talking about the sum of the edges between two points? So wouldnt that necessitate h and g being on the same "scale" or at least be measuring the same thing even if in abstract? e.g. if the weight of the edges correlates to price in a range 1-10 and the heuristic is a measure of the euclidean distance in a range 1000-10000 wouldnt that fuck it up?

Comment: Correct, you could say that they need to be in the same scale, although to be completely sure, I would need a formal definition. But the only important thing is that $h(n)$ is a lower bound on the "true value". I.e. $h(n)$ needs to be smaller than the sum of edges, as you say, from $n$ to goal.